# How to write a custom bridge (for testnets)

Tags: proof-of-stake, mint, proof-of-work, bridge, burn

I have two private testnets running on a network - one is Ethereum using PoW consensus and the other is running Ethereum with PoS consensus

i want to create a bridge between them - say i want to move ether, from the chain running PoW to the chain running PoS.

how can i achieve this?

P.S : in case i do have to write a bridge - kindly let me know if there are any relevant  resources which teach how to write bridges in ethereum !